# How do you change the logging location of a SDL Tridion Publisher?

Tags: tridion

I would like to enable logging on publishing on a SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 implementation. How do I enable publishing logging, raise/lower the detail level and change the location to a custom location away from the %TRIDION_HOME%?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must enable Publisher logging in the Tridion MMC snap-in (Publisher settings).

Once this is done, you can control the location, level and details of the logging by editing the file:
\Tridion\bin\TCMPublisher.exe.config